# SSH Connection disconnecting

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

My SSH to GCP keeps on disconnecting too frequently. It disconnects practically every minute and is becoming very frustrating. It has happened only since last week and before that all was working fine. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Is it disconnecting when the SSH session is idle for a specific time or does it disconnect randomly?

Comment: Which zone is your VM in? Do you know more precisely when the problem started? How do you open the ssh connections?

Comment: I opened an ssh connection to a VM and left it alone for hours. After 4 hours it was still connected. So my guess is the problem is likely on your network. Maybe you have NAT or a firewall which drops connections. You should grab a packet capture of the problem as seen from both the client machine and the VM.

Comment: You may want to make the connection using the `-vvv` parameter to have debug info. That will probably point you to the reason for disconnection. If you cannot find a misconfiguration, the you may want to try [Mosh](https://mosh.org/) which is specifically made to withstand some erratic and heavily filtered networks and may provide relief to your situation.

Comment: @Thomas .. It disconnects randomly ... even when I am writing a command.

Comment: @kasperd - Zone is us-central1-c ... It started about 10 days back and is still continuing. I access it via the web browser SSH connection.

Comment: I don't think this is a firewall connection because the problem persists when I login from multiple networks.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser) one -> Intermittent disconnects. Try with a native SSH client or contact Google.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have this issue with only one instance or multiple instances. Did you test creating new instance and use SSH. There are few known [issues](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#known_issues) including intermittent disconnects when connect to GCE VM instance using SSH from the browser. Are you having this issue when connect using other [methods](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#sshingcloud)?